# how open viewcontroller from collection view?

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to development in ios and I would like to know how to open a new viewcontroller from collection view.

I have my collection view, now i want to open my viewcontroller color purple when image 1 is pressed and open mu viewcontroller color cyan when image 2 is pressed.

I would like to know what image the user clicked to then show the viewcontroller

I add an image.

[image]

Comment: You could use the didSelectItemAt  of UICollectionViewDelegate or add a button on each cell and implement the action event. Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 2):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  let secondVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondView") as! SecondViewController
  secondVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
/// if use navigation controller
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)
/// if use viewController
self.present(secondVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```